# What's the "dimensionality" of a matrix (not dimension!)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that a $m\times n$ matrix has *dimension*... well, $m\times n$.

However, in a paper (not a mathematics paper!) I encountered the term *dimensionality* of a matrix, whose definition is nowhere to be found.

Apparently, the dimensionality has to be a scalar, as it says e.g.:

"For all real, skew-symmetric matrices, the rank is 2 times the dimensionality, as eigenvalues come in conjugate imaginary pairs."

So, can anyone tell me what I have to deal with here?

Thanks!

Comment: In this case the matrix is square $n\times n$ and $n$ is the dimensionality (technically, dimension is something that vector spaces have, not matrices).

Comment: It's basically the "size" of a square matrix.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, So what's the definition of dimensionality?

Comment: No, @HennoBrandsma the dimension is the size. I'm talking about dimensionality.

Comment: What @TobiasKildetoft said: a matrix does not have dimension $n$ (a matrix is not a vector space (nor a topological space, etc..)) so does not have a "dimension". It has the number of columns and the number of rows, and if these are equal we call that the dimensionality.

Comment: No, Henno is correct. A matrix does not have a dimension, it has a dimensionality (which is what you are calling the dimension).

Comment: On the one hand, I agree with everyone else that the dimensionality of an $n\times n$ matrix is $n$. On the other hand, the rank of an $n\times n$ matrix cannot be greater than $n$, much less equal to $2n$, so something is wrong here. Maybe if you posted a link to the article where you found this claim (why do so many people fail to do this??) we would be able to clear up the situation.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to find information on the 'dimensionality' of a matrix is a bit difficult for me! But I think I figured it out in laymens terms:

The dimensionality of a vector space is the number of unique ways a set of vectors 'point' within the vector space.

Consider a 2x2 vector space  $\vec{V} = \begin{bmatrix}
   a       & b \\
    c       & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$

The dimensionality of $\vec{V}$ is $4$, because it has four independant components that 'point' in different directions and $\vec{V}$ can be represented by a set of four basis vectors:
$A\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}  + B\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+ C\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} +D\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. The basis vectors are arbitrary and all kinds of sets can satisfy the basis. But, you get what I mean.

Also consider the vector space $\vec{A}=A_x\hat{x} + A_y\hat{y} + 0\hat{z}$. It has dimensionality $2$ because the components only exist in the $x$-$y$ plane.

Lastly, consider the vector space $\vec{A}=k\hat{x} + k\hat{y} + k\hat{z}$. This one is tricky, because $\vec{A}$ appears to point in three different directions. But since the components are all the same, the vector space is just a one dimensional line from $($-$\infty,$ -$\infty,$ -$\infty)$ to $(\infty, \infty, \infty)$. So the dimensionality is $1$.

Also, I am still confused a bit about vector space dimensionality, so if anyone cares to right my wrongs, please do! I'm really unclear about this kind of stuff and any help is appreciated. Thanks!